# Python Selenium WebScraping Get Div Content

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to webscraping, I have a small problem for which I cannot find the solution, I am trying to webscrape information on a site. I managed to fill out a login form with selenium, but I cannot retrieve the contents of the div (see screen), yet I am using the functions present in the documentation.

Thanks in advance (sorry I'm french)

[Div content (here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu2AO.png)

[My python code (no error just not print in console)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDWUn.png)